# how to escape a JavaScript function argument variable to be used in a statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, vue.js

I have the following code block

```
  data () {
    return {
      parkingExtra: false,
      housekeepingExtra: false,
      storageExtra: false,
      gymExtra: false,
      spaExtra: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    enableExtraPriceField: function(elementToToggle) {
      this.elementToToggle = true;
      var el = document.getElementById(elementToToggle);
      el.disabled = false;
      el.placeholder = '';
      el.focus();
    }
  }
```

The elementToToggle argument will always equal a value to one of the data variables (I'm using vue.js by the way) such as parkingExtra, housekeepingExtra etc. How can I make the elementToToggle variable in this.elementToToggle = true use the respective value, i.e. to turn it into this.housekeepingExtra = true for example? As it's not using elementToToggle as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object property by variable name `this[elementToToggle]`:

```
methods: {
  enableExtraPriceField: function(elementToToggle) {
    this[elementToToggle] = true;
    var el = document.getElementById(elementToToggle);
    el.disabled = false;
    el.placeholder = '';
    el.focus();       
  }
}
```